# How to take punctuation into account in "Text to speech"

Tags: flutter, text-to-speech

I have started using the package flutter_tts to make it possible for my users to hear words and sentences (I am building an app to learn English vocabulary).
Has anyone using this package managed to:

- find a male voice for the English language
- find a way to take punctuation into account; if a sentence is a question, intonation should be different.

I have looked around in documentation and tutorials, but can't find anything.
There is something called "speech marks" in the pud.dev documentation for flutter_tts, but it's nowhere written what it is or what it does.

Anyone using this package could help me on these points?

Comment: From a quick look it seems that package uses the underlying TTS engine of the OS, just passing the string straight through. So punctuation handling would be handled at that level. It should *just work*, so may depend on your device settings and targeted language. Speech marks are probably for SSML support (getting back timing of audio, not changing the intonation)

Comment: Thank you for the information. This answers my question.